# Opencv with Python: pointPolygonTest gives obviously wrong result

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I have a contour below. As I wanted to extract all the pixels inside this contour and black out everything else to remove noise, I used cv2.pointPolygonTest for the purpose.

Below are the code I used to attempt to create the mask.

```
inside_or_not = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],dtype = np.int32)
for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,img.shape[1]):
        inside_or_not[i,j] = cv2.pointPolygonTest(body_line,(i,j),False)
```

Only 2 points were found to be inside the point. On top of that, I expect the number of points lying on the contour, hence returning 0 from the cv2.pointPolygonTest should match the number of pixels defining the contour. However when I run sum(sum(inside_or_not == 0)), it does not match the No. of pixels on the contour.
I also used mouse click to click a point obviously inside the contour and put that point into the test; but -1 is returned indicating the test failed.

I also used a approxPolyDP function to attempt to approximate the contour with less vertices. This time a bit more points were returned. However I have no idea why!

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: what about: 1) findContours, 2) drawContours(... CV_FILLED ... 3) findNonZero (optional)?

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure how drawContours with color filled could have an impact, as surely a drawing function will not return or modify any existing objects....?

Comment: can you upload a png image? jpeg creates unwanted artifacts

Comment: Hi I have changed it to png.

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if it fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a well defined contour, you can simply use `findContour` with `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` to detect the external contour, and draw the region inside it with `drawContour(..., CV_FILLED)`. Once you have the mask, you can use `copyTo` to copy only the parts of your original image according to the mask.

Here an example, it's C++, but the porting to python is straightforward.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image_shape");

    // Just to have a background image the same size of your image.
    Mat3b bkg = imread("path_to_image_background");
    resize(bkg, bkg, img.size());

    // Convert to gray
    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Get external contour
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(gray.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // contours has size 1 here, you need to check this in a real application

    // Create a mask with the inner part of the contour
    Mat1b mask(img.size(), uchar(0));
    drawContours(mask, contours, 0, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

    // Create a black RGB image
    Mat3b res(img.size(), Vec3b(0,0,0));

    // Copy the image according to the mask
    bkg.copyTo(res, mask);

    imshow("result", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks you very much for your answer. Maybe I should have made it clearer. I have a numpy array img, representing the original image file. Also, I have this defined contour. I want to have a numpy array named filtered_img so that every pixel outside this contour will have RGB value 0, and every pixel inside the contour will have the same RGB value as it is defined in img object

Comment: @wudanao check the updated answer. Once you have the mask (obtained with `drawContour`), use `copyTo` to copy only the masked part of the image.

Comment: wow this is beautiful, and also promising. I forgot the drawcontours actually modify the original numpy array. I will go back tonight and try to implement it. Thanks!