# Free hand crop image on android use OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv

I'm a newbie to OpenCV, I am writing an app require free hand crop using this tool. Have tried pointPolygonTest method to copy the pixel inside the polygon return very slowly. So any solution for more quicly?

Comment: You can use `copyTo` with a mask. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31905865/5008845)

Comment: Thank @Miki
It worked with the -1 instead of CV_FILLED as the param